# return a list of all the occurences of a foreign key ID in the books table - symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

In my db schema, I have two related tables between books and bookpermit where I am trying to return a list of all the occurences of a foreign key id in the bookpermit table as bookpermit is related to books with a foreign key. Here is the sample db schema

bookpermit

```
id | userfk  | bookfk   |
1  | 6       | 6        |
2  | 6       | 7        |
3  | 7       | 7        |
4  | 8       | 8        |
```

books

```
id | name  | uerfk   |
1  | xyz1   | 6       |
2  | xyz2   | 7       |
3  | xyz3   | 8       |
```

In my controller I have this code function that takes a parameter of the user that uploaded the books and the user bookpermit table

```
public function displayAction(Request $request, $user, $bookpermit)
    {
         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $bookLists= $em->getRepository("xxxBundle:Books")->findBy(
        array(
            "usersfk" => $user,
            "usersfk" => $bookpermit
        )
    );

    $data = array();

    foreach ($bookLists as $bookList)
    {

        array_push($data, $this->serialize($bookLists));
    }


    $response = new Response(json_encode($data), 200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return $response;
    }
```

In my routing.yml file I have this code snippet that take two parameters
of the user and bookpermit

```
display_book_by_permission:
    pattern:  /displaybookbypermission/{user}/{imagepermit}
    defaults: { _controller:  xxxBundle:Books:display, _format: ~ }
    requirements:
        _method: GET
```

if I should access the above routing with this endpoint

```
http://localhost:88/books/web/app_dev.php/displaybookbypermission/6/7
```

assuming that 6 is the user ID 7 is the book permit ID the result returns xyz2. Now my challenge is to be able to return xyz2 and zyz1 from the books table for instance

```
http://localhost:88/books/web/app_dev.php/displaybookbypermission/6/xyz2+xyz1
```

Instead of the parameter returning just one occurence from the books table. All ideas and help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look in the param converter annotation
http://symfony.com/app.php/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

You will be able to get the parameters you want, in a custom repository method